# java Вылетает Exception java.rmi.ConnectIOException

Tags: java, исключения, vmware, rmi

Написал , RMI клиент-сервер , на localhost все работает, проблема возникает при работе на виртуалке , сервер запускается и работает (на основной машине)
Здесь создается RMI registry

```
            CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
            CreditCardService creditCardService = new CreditCardService();
            OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
            ItemService itemService = new ItemService();
            ICustomerService stub0 = (ICustomerService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(customerService, 0);
            IItemService stub1 = (IItemService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(itemService, 0);
            IOrderService stub2 = (IOrderService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(orderService, 0);
            ICreditCardService stub3 = (ICreditCardService) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(creditCardService, 0);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

            registry.rebind("CustomerService", stub0);
            registry.rebind("ItemService", stub1);
            registry.rebind("OrderService", stub2);
            registry.rebind("CreditCardService", stub3);
```

При вызове удаленного метода на RMI клиенте вылетает Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.232.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.readAll(Unknown Source)
    at client.main.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:60)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 7 more
```

Код клиента :

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(args[0], Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
        ICustomerService customerService = (ICustomerService) registry.lookup("CustomerService");
        IOrderService orderService = (IOrderService) registry.lookup("OrderService");
        ICreditCardService creditCardService = (ICreditCardService) registry.lookup("CreditCardService");
        IItemService itemService = (IItemService) registry.lookup("ItemService");
```

Он отрабатывает нормально, сам Exception вылетает при вызове методов orderService,itemService и т.д. (объектов заглушек)

Сама виртуалка пингуется нормально , сервер с виртуалке тоже , пробовал XP и Ubuntu , фаервол везде отключен

Еще странность в том, что в Exception указан ip 192.168.232.1 , хотя клиент запускается из консоли с параметром 192.168.228.1 1099

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена ! У хоста было два виртуальных сетевых адаптера , и при запуске клиентского приложения , он пытался подключиться к второму адаптеру, решилось отключение ненужного виртуального адаптера